# Google Maps SDK for iOS cannot connect or validate APIKey

Tags: ios, google-maps

```
2013-10-11 18:51:20.384 FreeBus[11643:a0b] Google Maps SDK for iOS cannot connect or validate APIKey: Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
```

My bundle identifier:

```
com.regis.freebus
```

after com.regis.freebus exists one word FreeBus like: com.regis.freebusFreebus

In Google Console, how i specific my bundle identifier?

Answer (score 0):

You should not have two words. It should be identical to the bundle identifier under your project info (press the project icon and then the leftmost tab.)